# How to Dismiss the Linear Progress Bar (v-progress-linear) on an Autocomplete (v-autocomplete)?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, vuetify.js

The Vuetify Autocomplete component, `v-autocomplete`, comes with a built-in `v-progress-linear` that is "turned on" by setting the `v-autocomplete`'s `loading` prop:

```html
<v-autocomplete ref="control1" loading>
   <!-- redacted for brevity --> 
</v-autocomplete>
```

... which is as handy as a pocket on a shirt, but I can't turn the dumb thing off after I've loaded my items:

```js
this.$refs.control1.loading = false;
this.$refs.control1.loading = null;
```

... neither of these seem to be working. It just sits there, indeterminately progressing despite my best efforts to dismiss it.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not overlooking, overthinking :)

You can use the v-bind directive on boolean props as well.

Try something like this:

```
<template>
   <v-autocomplete ref="control1" :loading="showProgress">
      <!-- redacted for brevity --> 
   </v-autocomplete>
   <button @click="hideProgres">Hide Progress Linear</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showProgress: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    hideProgress() {
      this.showProgress = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Then simply call `this.hideProgress()` when you want to hide the v-progress-linear component

EDIT: It's worth noting that you should never try to change props in an upstream manner (from the component whose props need mutation), you should always change them in a downstream manner (from the component that is the parent of the component whose props need to be changed).